# SKLabelNode higher when it contains (q,y,p,g or j)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

For exemple I have two SKLabelNode: "Easy" and "Medium"

I set them at the same height but because easy contains a 'y', it is higher because of his tail

How can I put them at the same height?

Comment: What is the real problem? Why do you need the same height?

Comment: On the screen they don't appear to be at the same place on the y axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set them in order to have the same `position.y` value

```
let easy = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
easy.text = "Easy"
easy.fontSize = 45
easy.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 200, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
self.addChild(easy)

let medium = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
medium.text = "Medium"
medium.fontSize = 45
medium.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 200, y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
self.addChild(medium)
```

[image]

Comment: It works but for my project I need them to be vertically centered I've just realized that it was the problem. Is it posible to have the same y position if they are vertically centered?

Comment: @ClémentBisaillon: Sure, just try it ;-)